# Is it possible to rotate pixels using this 2x2 matrix?

Tags: math, opengl, graphics, matrix, rotation

[image: 2x2 matrix to rotate]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Suppose i have (x,y) 2D pixels for image, now i want to rotate these pixels around X axis.
Can i use that 2x2 matrix above?

When is that 2x2 matrix used? How is that 2x2 matrix used?

Does opengl use that matrix internally or does opengl use the 3x3 matrix?

How is the theta degree measured in the above R matrix?
Is it the angle between (0,0) to (x,y) and (0,0) to (x',y')?

Comment: You can't rotate 2D pixels around the X axis. Didn't you learn last time?

Comment: Err, for two dimensions, you rotate around a _point,_ not an axis You can _reflect_ across an axis but I'm not sure if that's what you were after.

Comment: You basically rotate around the Z axis, the one that's going out of the screen...

Comment: That's confusing, someone is saying rotating around Z axis, someone is saying rotating around a point. My question was: 'When is that matrix used?' Does opengl use that matrix?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Did you read this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix , here it says, for 2 dimenstional, you use that 2x2 matrix. That was my confusion.

Comment: @prime, that link says it rotates it around the _origin_ (a point), not the X axis.

Comment: prime: yeah, you can give the matrix to openGl and it will do the work for you (-: (if that was the question)

Comment: @paxdiablo, Then i can't understand the concetp of rotation around X axis, how can i think about rotation around axis, like around x axis or z axis?

Comment: If it's the rotation around zero(0,0) point, then how is the theta degree measured in the above R matrix? Is it the angle between (0,0) to (x,y) and (0,0) to (x',y') straight line?

Comment: @prime, if you're talking about the z axis, you're in 3D space, not 2D. There, my comments do not apply.

Comment: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_anglestoaxes.html , `Rotation about Left(X) Axis (Pitch)` In 3D space, from that 3x3 matrix we can say that if we want to rotate around X axis, then the value of angle for X remains 1, and the angle value of Y and Z change. So for 2D space if i change the value of Y only and the value of X is fixed, that means, Y will be increased or decrease(up or down, X is fixed), can't we say it like rotating around X axis?

Comment: @prime If that's the question, Then **NO**. OpenGL doesn't rotate pixels anywhere in its whole pipeline.

Comment: @ChristianRau, What does that mean?

Comment: @prime What it says, OpenGL doesn't rotate any pixels.

Comment: OpenGL uses a 4x4 matrix.  It rotates 3d points, represented as homogeneous coordinates of the form `[x, y, z, w]`.  A regular 3d point `(x, y, z)` corresponds to homogeneous coordinates `[x, y, z, 1]`.  A 3d rotation about the 3d x-axis will update the `y` and `z` coordinates, while leaving the `x` and `w` coordinates unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is look at your point as a 1X2 matrix and multiply it with the R matrix. This will give you a 2X1 matrix with is the new point.

[x] X [Cos(a)  -Sin(a)] = [newX, newY]
[y] X [Sin(a)   Cos(a)]

The math:
newX = xCos(a) -ySin(a)
newY = xSin(a) +yCos(a)

This will rotate the point (x,y) about `a` degrees around the (0,0) point.

Note make sure you use the correct dimension (degrees or radians) with a, Cos and Sin.

Comment: Exactly what I was writing. @prime : when you say about an axis, this would rotate it around an imaginary axis, perpendicular to your screen at (0,0) as Rosee indicates.

Comment: Can you give an example of rotation around X axis ?

Comment: If it's the rotation around zero(0,0) point, then how is the theta degree measured in the above R matrix? Is it the angle between (0,0) to (x,y) and (0,0) to (x',y') straight line?

Comment: @prime: you can't rotate around an axis in 2d space. You can only mirror. And scale. But not rotate.

Comment: A. you can't rotate around the X axis - it will get you "out" of the screen (-:    B. Yes - it's the angle between (0,0)->(x,y) and (0,0)->(x',y')

Comment: @SigTerm: you can rotate in 2D. think of a circle (which is in 2D...) if you have a point on that circle and you want to move it to a different point on the same circle you can rotating it around center of your circle.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel: in 2d space you can only rotate around a POINT. Not around an AXIS. Rotating around axis leaves you single dimension for rotation, and there are no circles in 1D. Let's say you want to rotate point (x: 0; y: 1) around axis (x: 1, y: 1) by 90 degrees. What will be new point coordinates? Think about it. Also by rotating new point around same axis by -90 degrees you should get original point. In 2d that's not gonna happen - to rotate around axis you need at least 3 dimensions.

Comment: @SigTerm: Semantics... what I was saying is that you rotate around an `imaginary` Z axis. which will keep you in your 2D space.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel: Please note that OP wants to rotate around X axis in 2d. Imaginary axis or not, you can't do that in 2d space.

Comment: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_anglestoaxes.html , `Rotation about Left(X) Axis (Pitch)` In 3D space, from that 3x3 matrix we can say that if we want to rotate around X axis, then the value of angle for X remains 1, and the angle value of Y and Z change. So for 2D space if i change the value of Y only and the value of X is fixed, that means, Y will be increased or decrease(up or down, X is fixed), can't we say it like rotating around X axis?

Comment: nope. when rotate around X axis the original point and the new point must have the same distance from the X axis. in the 3D it mean that y^2 + z^2 = y`^2 + z`^2. in 2D it doesn't have any meaning...

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose i have (x,y) 2D pixels for image, now i want to rotate these pixels around X axis. Can i use that 2x2 matrix above?

No, because you **can't** rotate anything around x axis (or any other axis) in 2d space. in 2d space you can only rotate around a point (and **mirror** around axis). Matrix you provided rotates around zero point (x = 0, y = 0). Another things is that you rotate vertices or texture coordinates, not pixels. You can rotate around an axis only in 3d space.

> Does opengl use that matrix internally or does opengl use the 3x3 matrix?

That's up to driver to decide. Most likely Fixed-Function OpenGL uses 4x4 matrix internally (allows rotation+translation+projection in 3d space). However, nothing stops you from writing a fragment shader that will use 2x2 matrix.

> How is the theta degree measured in the above R matrix? Is it the angle between (0,0) to (x,y) and (0,0) to (x',y')?

The answer is yes. It is an angle between   0;0 -> x';y' and 0;0 -> x;y. However, you still can't rotate around "X axis" in 2D. You can only rotate around a point. And because your rotation matrix is 2x2, you can only rotate, scale, mirror and skew around (0; 0) point. For anything else that requires shifting/translation you'll either need 3x3 matrix or 4x4 matrix (i.e. operate on 3d vectors for 2d operations, set z cordinate to zero).

Comment: Everyone knows, angle is not straight line. I edited my original question. I think, you will understand the question now clearly. `How is the theta degree measured in the above R matrix? Is it the angle between (0,0) to (x,y) and (0,0) to (x',y')?`